# Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null` google maps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I am trying to move an implementation of google maps into React. It works in the jsfiddle but I'm having trouble getting this to work in React due to having to use CDN's and jquery.

Google maps example - https://jsfiddle.net/quqz096d/16

Here is my implementation into React - https://codesandbox.io/s/n3ly2zyj5p

2 problems I'm having is that I am having to use CDN's to load the external resources as 'wicket' doesn't get recognized when installed via npm and I get the error `Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null` when initializing the map.

How can I get npm to recognize wicket so I don't have to use the CDN and how can I display the map and get around the error?

**Hello.js**

```
/* eslint-disable */
import React from 'react'
import './styles.css'
import './map.js'

export default class Hello extends React.Component {
  render(){
    $(document).ready(function () {

      function UseWicketToGoFromGooglePolysToWKT(poly1, poly2) {
        var wicket = new Wkt.Wkt();

        wicket.fromObject(poly1);
        var wkt1 = wicket.write();

        wicket.fromObject(poly2);
        var wkt2 = wicket.write();

        return [wkt1, wkt2];
      }

      function UseJstsToTestForIntersection(wkt1, wkt2) {
        // Instantiate JSTS WKTReader and get two JSTS geometry objects
        var wktReader = new jsts.io.WKTReader();
        var geom1 = wktReader.read(wkt1);
        var geom2 = wktReader.read(wkt2);

      }

      function UseJstsToDissolveGeometries(wkt1, wkt2) {
        // Instantiate JSTS WKTReader and get two JSTS geometry objects
        var wktReader = new jsts.io.WKTReader();
        var geom1 = wktReader.read(wkt1);
        var geom2 = wktReader.read(wkt2);

        // In JSTS, "union" is synonymous with "dissolve"
        var dissolvedGeometry = geom1.union(geom2);

        // Instantiate JSTS WKTWriter and get new geometry's WKT
        var wktWriter = new jsts.io.WKTWriter();
        var wkt = wktWriter.write(dissolvedGeometry);

        // Use Wicket to ingest the new geometry's WKT
        var wicket = new Wkt.Wkt();
        wicket.read(wkt);

        // Assemble your new polygon's options, I used object notation
        var polyOptions = {
          strokeColor: '#ff0000',
          strokeOpacity: 0.8,
          strokeWeight: 2,
          fillColor: '#ff0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.35
        };

        // Let wicket return a Google Polygon with the options you set above
        var newPoly = wicket.toObject(polyOptions);


        polygon1.setMap(null);
        polygon2.setMap(null);
        polygon4.setMap(null);
        polygon5.setMap(null);

        newPoly.setMap(map);
      }


      var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.08804, 14.42076),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

      var coords = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.262985388398, 16.651552652553),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.268154293695, 16.696169517975),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.279279281222, 16.684044046655),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.29051372157, 16.69354790883),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.291693807108, 16.696711972181),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.291754288729, 16.700906003794),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.287224249824, 16.708018278815),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.269030413678, 16.716675506228),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.264399780154, 16.741519717396),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.257603048662, 16.755486775372),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.250805381075, 16.764647314794),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.224771273353, 16.709762631879),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.211636932658, 16.723347359512),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.190309978235, 16.733155536853),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.180168244216, 16.73897258718),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.169575489284, 16.744102991998),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.162404281723, 16.749490888883),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.153547978232, 16.756852891603),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.133280070767, 16.786993699245),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.107610095774, 16.797050125784),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.09345145266, 16.767467010234),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.080895297287, 16.738570187728),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.080491255717, 16.713371482742),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.072497012164, 16.703751047716),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.056097057925, 16.680771248057),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.046595816216, 16.642153144456),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.020460102381, 16.634173743535),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.028989499528, 16.606281622887),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.017651016771, 16.588388777446),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.035732241135, 16.572490068959),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.06977908486, 16.580280630492),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.091541070978, 16.569729162022),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.093756140248, 16.546612884063),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.094414014421, 16.509563030607),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.123726846521, 16.495515801661),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.141450293969, 16.487353801526),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.182287496702, 16.490864775023),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.231794094402, 16.507802307393),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.251996444572, 16.486292840573),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.262766673059, 16.496309133774),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.262781359229, 16.501518908421),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.256566333557, 16.531971044116),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.295657825466, 16.487131907305),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.326781008179, 16.532722798718),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.297128289052, 16.619936823457),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.288287925981, 16.646039397999),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.262985388398, 16.651552652553),
      ];

      var coords2 = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.2586746285, 16.548371315002),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.277604734014, 16.582703590393),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.296079782666, 16.619782447815),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.287123047871, 16.643128395081),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.261587425184, 16.650338172913),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.266964444325, 16.700119972229),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.254193067134, 16.712307929993),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.241642530476, 16.737198829651),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.229313005054, 16.715569496155),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.225052999213, 16.707673072815),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.212046498864, 16.72209262848),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.204083934969, 16.758828163147),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.173455370467, 16.769127845764),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.174016503645, 16.788182258606),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.165486592872, 16.801915168762),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.133261701694, 16.784234046935),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.109332116515, 16.794962882995),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.108320753033, 16.742520332337),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.095957977994, 16.722350120545),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.092136133539, 16.67814731598),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.083142397663, 16.620812416077),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.079375786844, 16.610770225524),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.082805100877, 16.58630847931),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.119556967033, 16.554894447327),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.131689219618, 16.529488563538),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.149208344183, 16.470437049866),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.159312714511, 16.387009620667),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.168068168316, 16.34855747223),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.193399748804, 16.343171596528),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.212214708212, 16.3707447052),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.23671108962, 16.38288974762),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.245676979472, 16.402201652527),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.252176231763, 16.42288684845),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.250831629069, 16.487946510315),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.262035532491, 16.49721622467),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.253520797832, 16.531205177308),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.2586746285, 16.548371315002),
      ];

      var coords3 = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.053694570768, 15.73890209198),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.060300338732, 15.741423368454),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.06277640633, 15.740881562233),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.068063880789, 15.738636553288),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.090232729029, 15.760430842639),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.085633529415, 15.783684253693),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.078631917353, 15.809079408646),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.071866851888, 15.809352993966),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.055678463163, 15.810270309448),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.058282197455, 15.819840431214),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.051204256403, 15.828820466996),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.043904789772, 15.830676555634),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.030460394663, 15.833745002747),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.026742020752, 15.845045149327),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.020967459894, 15.84202632308),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.019493982719, 15.834200978279),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.011503675166, 15.820237398148),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.99085647193, 15.817844867707),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.983544381282, 15.79580783844),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.99560183777, 15.783920288086),
        new google.maps.LatLng(49.995146634027, 15.749373435974),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.005891051388, 15.748558044434),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.017363823547, 15.711307525634),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.028682227671, 15.705685615539),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.03916419239, 15.686995983123),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.050525683613, 15.728216171264),
      ]

      var coords4 = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.086776271667, 14.411187171937),

        new google.maps.LatLng(50.093446313761, 14.405543804168),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.093611504263, 14.407582283019),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.098112726191, 14.465957880019),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.095710750594, 14.458061456681),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.091932040978, 14.438931941987),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.086266859813, 14.438084363938),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.081557985814, 14.433567523955),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.079774826525, 14.430488348007),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.077647341221, 14.419426918031),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.073557347011, 14.415392875672),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.067208213772, 14.416809082031),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.066223403061, 14.420553445817),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.062759187941, 14.421186447145),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.061677860817, 14.416154623032),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.047701064336, 14.410994052886),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.051441926838, 14.406348466873),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.062869385515, 14.40908432007),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.081378984402, 14.406681060789),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.081764525075, 14.408440589906),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.081819602062, 14.408912658691),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.081874678984, 14.410028457641),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.08237036844, 14.41123008728),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.086776271667, 14.411187171937),
      ]

      var coords5 = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.06306406683, 14.4095993042),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.063284460323, 14.412860870362),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.06802267553, 14.409084320069),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.070887415799, 14.409599304198),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.075845215724, 14.41062927246),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.0836664799, 14.410114288329),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.091183605008, 14.413719177246),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.097708504849, 14.418439865111),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.10293879554, 14.418439865111),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.10668223191, 14.417581558228),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.111030856788, 14.420757293702),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.110865726348, 14.417066574096),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.111195986659, 14.408655166626),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.11174641545, 14.401874542236),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.112792212729, 14.397239685059),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.11438838559, 14.393978118897),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.121212800443, 14.393463134765),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.116259692911, 14.378528594971),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.112461963426, 14.368658065796),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.112847254059, 14.353637695313),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.115158932757, 14.331150054932),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.116259692911, 14.318962097169),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.111085900142, 14.304885864259),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.104590347649, 14.290294647218),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.09319347897, 14.295186996461),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.081243126025, 14.292011260987),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.064000732187, 14.276990890504),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.048515857306, 14.273643493653),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.042452801429, 14.271926879883),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.045374187593, 14.308319091797),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.040688859551, 14.318962097168),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.040302988625, 14.33183670044),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.045732458563, 14.341707229615),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.046862372565, 14.34986114502),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.042066944681, 14.35715675354),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.058876398045, 14.390029907227),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.063064066831, 14.40788269043),
        new google.maps.LatLng(50.06306406683, 14.4095993042),
      ]
      //brno
      var polygon1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: [coords],
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#00FF00',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
      });

      //brno
      var polygon2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: [coords2],
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#0000FF',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
      });

      // pardubice
      var polygon3 = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: [coords3],
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#0000FF',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
      });

      var polygon4 = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: [coords4],
        strokeColor: '#000000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#0000FF',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
      });

      var polygon5 = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: [coords5],
        strokeColor: '#ff00ff',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#ff00ff',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
      });

      polygon1.setMap(map);
      polygon2.setMap(map);
      polygon3.setMap(map);
      polygon4.setMap(map);
      polygon5.setMap(map);

      function DoEverything() {
        var wkt = UseWicketToGoFromGooglePolysToWKT(polygon4, polygon5);
        UseJstsToTestForIntersection(wkt[0], wkt[1]);
        UseJstsToDissolveGeometries(wkt[0], wkt[1]);
      }

      function DoEverything2() {
        var wkt = UseWicketToGoFromGooglePolysToWKT(polygon1, polygon2);
        UseJstsToTestForIntersection(wkt[0], wkt[1]);
        UseJstsToDissolveGeometries(wkt[0], wkt[1]);
      }

      DoEverything()
      DoEverything2()

    })

    return(
      <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the version of jquery and this looks to have solved this